# Do CMS make things slower for people who know web development (e.g. building a static page)?

Tags: content-management-system

For instance, when I use Wordpress to make my own websites, I find myself consuming time because of the website loading time (e.g. clicking Publish or Update). Plus I can't copy/paste content, etc.

Do CMS make things like static pages slower for you?

Comment: If it doesn't help you, stop using it. What's the question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the CMS and the purpose.

If you just need a blog, use Wordpress.

If you just need a static site, might as well write it yourself, otherwise CMS setup is a waste of time as you will have to write it all anyway.

If you need something more complicated, then a powerful CMS is a must otherwise you will waste months on a 3 day job. (**Drupal**, Joomla)